# How to add values under the same group in Pivot Table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a Pivot table that has several fields as attached in the picture. I would like to add all the quantities under the same ID 1, I have tried to moved this field into "Values" are but I received an error

> "The field you are moving cannot be placed in that area of the report".

Are there any ways I can add different values under the same group? I would very much appreciate for assistance regarding my problem.

Please find attached a picture of my Pivot Table.

[image: Pivot Table]

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you are asking. Maybe provide an example of what you expect the results to look like.

Comment: Oh I want to tally up the value of quantity, for example the sum of quantity in this case is 2+3+4+5+6=20. So how do I sum them all up under the ID 1 instead of the values in separate lines?

Comment: Sorry I didn't follow up sooner. What I was suggesting it make a fake example of what you're looking for and maybe someone can suggest how to do.